# "alias : The term '-alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" error

Tags: android, keytool

I need "Debug signing certificate SHA-1" fingerprint in firebase.

But in commandline part

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

When I run this code I get an error like this:

```
C:\Users\Win10\Desktop\firebasse> keytool -list -v \
    >> -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
    Illegal option:  \
    keytool -list [OPTION]...
    
    Lists entries in a keystore
    
    Options:
    
     -rfc                    output in RFC style
     -alias <alias>          alias name of the entry to process
     -keystore <keystore>    keystore name
     -cacerts                access the cacerts keystore
     -storepass <arg>        keystore password
     -storetype <type>       keystore type
     -providername <name>    provider name
     -addprovider <name>     add security provider by name (e.g. SunPKCS11)
       [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -addprovider
     -providerclass <class>  add security provider by fully-qualified class name
       [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -providerclass
     -providerpath <list>    provider classpath
     -v                      verbose output
     -protected              password through protected mechanism
    
    Use "keytool -?, -h, or --help" for this help message
    -alias : The term '-alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
     or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    At line:2 char:1
    + -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystor ...
    + ~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-alias:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

Can anyone help with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your command line part is for a Unix (or Linux) shell where `\` is the escape character. On PowerShell the escape character is `` ` ``, so

```
keytool -list -v `
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

should do the trick. You can also put everything in one line:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```